# alert() in on change event can not be dismissed on Firefox

Tags: javascript, jquery, firefox, event-handling, alert

An `alert()` dialog in an on change event with jQuery can't be closed (I click "Ok" but nothing happens*) on the latest Firefox. On Internet Explorer the alert shows up one time and can be closed.

It seems that clicking the alert (re)triggers a change event in the input field on Firefox but I'm not sure, since the console log message does not show up.

```
$('input#i').on('keyup change', function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    console.log('alert ...');
    alert(1); // can't be closed on Firefox
    return false;
});
```

Full JavaScript Fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/powtac/w1md0bdd/

Tested on Firefox 52.0.1 (64-Bit) on Win 7 and IE 11 on Win 7.

* = At least I can not tell if something happens. The popup stays at the same position. the button can be clicked, it's style changes. I tested to dismiss the alert with keyboard (Enter) and mouse clicking the "Ok". Both cases did not remove the alert window.

**Update:**

Al.G. in this answer https://stackoverflow.com/a/43052301/22470 found a solution and explanation. In short: `keydown` instead `keyup`. Since this still does not explain the behavior when using mouse only I did some further tests and noticed that the alerts look different:

In my bad usecase where the popup can not be removed it looks like:

[image: bad alert]

When using the fix by Al.G, or removing one of the events the code is listening to it looks like:

[image]

This might be a hint that the alert is not yet fully drawn and showing already another popup or something is blocking rendering.

Comment: What you mean by _can't be closed_ ?

Comment: what version of firefox? works fine for me on windows with 44.0.2

Comment: Can you add the `navigator.userAgent` result. So that we can test it

Comment: Last version of FF,  v52. Same issue with 52.0.1 64-bit on linux

Comment: @SagarV Where should I add `navigator.userAgent`? To jsFiddle?

Comment: When you remove one event, the alert() works https://jsfiddle.net/w1md0bdd/3/

Comment: @R3tep Interesting. I want that any change inside the input triggers the event. Only one of both does not work, since copy/pasting with mouse would not trigger on pure "keyup" and "change" on the other hand does only trigger when leaving the input field. IE seems to work as expected. I would not mind if the event triggers two times, but not able to close the alert seems broken to me.

Comment: @Al.G. I did not say `disabled`, it's in a comment by somebody else. But the distinction between `keydown` and `keyup` is great! I do only click with the mouse on "Ok" this shold not trigger any key* events. But it works "as expected" when using `keydown` instead of  `keyup`. Do you want to add an answer?

Answer (score 3):

Putting my comment as an answer:

Actually the `Ok` button is not disabled. You *can* click it and the prompt *does* get closed, but:

- You close the alert, so the key focus goes back to the previous element which held it - i.e. the input element.
- Right after that, you release the key.
  Since the input element has the focus, you trigger a `keyup` event on it.
- That same `keyup` event function you attached gets executet again. Go to step 1 :)

A way to solve this is to use an event which won't be triggered after a key is release. What you need here is `keydown`.

---

- As for *why the `console.log` is not printed twice*:
  it probably is, just the browser does not add a new line in the console but shows a tiny number next to your message with the number of times the message was sent.
- To track *what types of events got triggered*: `console.log('alert ...' + e.type + Math.random());`
  I added a random number so that your browser does not squash your messages into one.
- Why *the letters do not appear in the input box* when using `keydown`: because you `preventDefault()` and `return false;` on the event. Any further event triggers are ignored.

Comment: Thanks a lot for the solution. This fits my expected behavior, thanks again! 
-
But your explanation does not explain my described bad behavior when using mouse only. Mouse clicking "Ok" should not trigger a keyup or keydown event.

Comment: @powtac Ok so this gives the answer: when you press e.g. `a` in the input, first the keydown/up event is fired (the first dialog), and then the change event (because "a" was added to the content of the input box) - the second dialog. These two stages have nothing to do with the way you close the dialog. Hope this helps!

Comment: sure, does also line up with my two images I added to the question. Still not a satisfying explanation why everything is blocked then. Probably it's a mixture of old browser behavior to print alerts on top but adding later the ability to checkbox-dismiss future popups into the highest rendered poupup, which then somehow triggers another event. or so.

Comment: You mean, why you can't interact with the page while the popup is present? That's the way [most] browsers work. Chromium [and Chrome, I suppose] behaves the same way.

Comment: About your solution. I can't edit the values anymore :-( because of the keydown ... (Background of the use case is to show an alert in case the value is not allowed). The alert triggers before the (maybe correct) new value reaches the input field.

Comment: That's because you block further propagation of the event (i.e. you stop at your function and disable any other events like the actual adding of the character to the input box). I removed `preventDefault()` and `return false` but that brings back the problem with the double-alert. I'll try to see why...

Answer (score 1):

Seems to be some sort of Firefox bug...

I guess you can workaround the issue with this code...

```
var popupOpen = false;
$('input#i').on('keyup change', function(ev) {
    ev.preventDefault();
    if (popupOpen == false) {
        popupOpen = true;
        console.log('alert ...');
        alert(1); // can't be closed on Firefox
        popupOpen = false;
    }
    return false;
});
```

Comment: So the bug is that alert() triggers another event?

Answer (score 0):

So, in FF44.0.2, it works as given. However, you may be getting some unexpected results because you're triggering twice. The keyup goes off, popping up the alert. The alert displaying removes focus from the input, which then triggers the change event on that same element, redisplaying the alert. I'm only getting it twice for each keyup, not an infinite loop.

Comment: Sure there might be a unexpected result because of listening to two triggers. But anyway the console.log should be executed before.

Comment: Oddly, on every browser I've tested, even if you put the console.log or edit the DOM before the alert, the alert will display first. Something with the asynchronicity of browsers? I'm not sure.